# Nested property where clause with Sails.js 1.0 not working anymore

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I just upgraded to Sails.js 1.0 and my decorator pattern stopped working.

This is what I have:

```
let model = Model.find()

model
  .where({
    'nested.property': {
      '>': 1
    }
  })

model.exec()
```

Gives me:

> Could not use the provided `where` clause.  Could not filter by
>   `nested.property`: `nested.property` is not a valid name for an
>   attribute in Waterline.  Even though this model (`model`) declares
>   `schema: false`, this is not allowed.

My data base is MongoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an undocumented feature that doesn't work anymore. Here the full quote:

> it looks like you were relying on some undocumented features of
>   Waterline that just happened to work in previous versions; namely
>   using native Mongo query syntax within a Waterline query. In 1.0,
>   you'll need to use the lower-level datastore functionality.

[Source](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/4133)

I ended up using [mquery](https://github.com/aheckmann/mquery) which supports dot notation (e. g. `nested.property`).